# Change Spinner Color And Place Spinner In The Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm new to Android Studio, I read some posts talking about that, but I didn't understand, can you help me?

I want to change the color of "the items in the list", I don't know if it's clear, I mean the color of the text that appears when you click on the spinner.

I saw in all the other question that you have to create a new layout (I tried but didn't manage to make it work), but when I created the new layout, how can I place the spinner in the right place of the activity layout?

If it isn't clear, please ask, thank you in advance

Comment: The "new layout" is simply the layout with a textview for your adapter that you will need to create.

Comment: @codeMagic but how can I do that? How can I reference my spinner in the other xml?

Comment: It is used when you create the adapter for your spinner. Look at the examples in that link. You create an xml file that just has a textview and set the color there. Then you use that when creating your adapter

Comment: @codeMagic which link?

Comment: The one that I closed this as. Check the top of the page ;)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, thanks! @codeMagic

Comment: @codeMagic I followed it, but it only changes the color of the selected items, and not the color of all the items, and the problem isn't solved in that question

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you not want to change the color of the selected item in the list? Do you want to change the color of all the items? Or the background of all of them in the spinner? Or the items themselves?

Comment: @codeMagic I found the solution, I'll post it nearly tomorrow

Comment: You must not have looked closely. The answer *is* in that link